# XOR Pair Of Elements In A List

Tags: python

I have a list of integer pairs

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 9), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

I want to take each element `(0,0)` then `(0,1)`, etc. pair, to XOR the two numbers between them and the result converted to binary.

Example: the `(0,2)` pair

0 decimal equals to 00110000 and 2 decimal equals to 00110010. The XOR of two will be 00000010.

I tried this, but nothing

```
import functools

test_list = [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2)]

for i in enumerate(test_list):
    res = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x ^ y, test_list)
    print(str(res))
```

Comment: so you want a list of the same size as initial where eahc pair has become its XOR ? please share the exact expected output

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "*0 decimal equals to 00110000*"?

Comment: The outup will be a list of each pair XOR. 0 decimal  is 00110000 binary ascii

Comment: why would you use the ASCII codes and not integers?

Comment: Because, I have to compare the result with an excisting list which has binary ascii elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite weird thing you try to do, but I believe you want:

```
lst = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 9), (1, 0), (1, 1)]

def to_ascii_code(c):
    return str(c).encode('ascii')[0]

out = [bin(to_ascii_code(a)^to_ascii_code(b)) for a,b in lst]
```

Output:

```
['0b0', '0b1', '0b10', '0b11', '0b100', '0b101', '0b110', '0b111', '0b1000', '0b1001', '0b1', '0b0']
```

Different format:

```
out = ['{0:08b}'.format(to_ascii_code(a)^to_ascii_code(b)) for a,b in lst]
```

Output:

```
['00000000', '00000001', '00000010', '00000011', '00000100', '00000101', '00000110', '00000111', '00001000', '00001001', '00000001', '00000000']
```

Comment: How to convert '0b0' to '00000000'?

Comment: check the last part of my answer

Comment: Also note that as you want to consider characters, it only works for single characters/digits!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I want. You are greate.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand the objective here. How about:

```
lst = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 9), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
nlst = [f'{(48+x)^(48+y):08b}' for x,y in lst]
print(nlst)
```

**Output:**

```
['00000000', '00000001', '00000010', '00000011', '00000100', '00000101', '00000110', '00000111', '00001000', '00001001', '00000001', '00000000']
```